# Finding difference between older data and current data before Database update call

Tags: java, mysql, database, redis

I have a requirement in my service, which is such that whenever an update call is made to database I want to compare current value(which I am updating) from previous value(present in database) and based on that need to take a decision(e.g. sending a notification). The only way which I was able  to think for this problem was to make a Database call(before update) and compare the events.
Can someone suggest a better approach for this?

Comment: suggest you use update trigger

Answer (score -1):

If the data volume is small, you can use cache to store data for quicker read.
Other than that, if you have bigger amount of data volume and want higher performance, I would suggest to have more replications to the database and use leader-followers type of config so that you can scale your read by adding more followers to it